# How to print a message in the terminal when debugging the Django app?

Tags: python, django

In the Django backend I have the following lines of code:

```
csvData = request.GET.get('csvData')

print(csvData)

X = pd.DataFrame(csvData)
```

It throws the following error message that I see in the terminal:

> X = pd.DataFrame(csvData)   File
>   "/Users/terr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py",
>   line 422, in **init**
>       raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')

However, the output of `print(csvData)` does not appear in the terminal. How can I print it out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code should work. If it isn't working, it could be that the csvData variable points to an empty string. Try deleting the last line (pd.DataFrame) and just printing CSVData so that you can see what happens when an error is not thrown.

Comment: Shouldn't it print anyway even if `csvData` is empty? `print(csvData)` goes before `pd.DataFrame(csvData)`. Actually `csvData` might be malformed. Therefore I wanted to print it out to see the format.

Comment: It'll still print, but if the terminal prints a blank string you won't see it. That's why I'm recommending that you get rid of the line causing the error and test to ensure that the string is printing correctly (and is what you expect to see). Just an easier way to debug.